# Add/Replace border with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

Beginner here,

I'm currently trying to show a border around  buttons every time I click on them.

Theborder would appear quarter by quarter (or 1/3) with the same `onclick="myFunction()`. I don't get it. How could I properly do it without using a new css class (here: `.test_skill`) ? I've tried to replace or modify the actual border in `.btn` but it's not doing anything.

My .html file is :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="testborder.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testbutton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-shipping-fast fa-inverse"></i></button>

        <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-address-card fa-inverse"></i></button>

        <!-- ici fa-inverse manquant -->
        <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-camera-retro"></i></button>

        <div id="skill_unlocked" onclick="myFunction()">
            <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-flag fa-inverse"></i></button>
        </div>

        <button class="btn"></button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

My .css file is :

```
 body{
    background-color: #575757;
    }

.btn{
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.6;
    border: 5px hidden;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    outline: none;
    }

.btn:hover{
    opacity: 0.9;
    background-color: #2B2B2B;
}

.fas{
    font-size: 28px;
}

.test_skill{
}
```

My .js file is :

```
function myFunction()
{
    document.getElementById('skill_unlocked').setAttribute("class", ".test_skill");
}
```

Bonus question : I'm not sure about the structure I've choose for my button with the`<div>`,`<button>`,`<i>` and `<a>` tags.I think that I'll have problems with it later becuase of the `class` tags a bit randomly placed. And it will not fit to what I want on the`css.file`

```js
function myFunction()
{
    document.getElementById('skill_unlocked').setAttribute("class", ".test_skill");
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #575757;
    }

.btn{
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.6;
    border: 5px hidden;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    outline: none;
    }

.btn:hover{
    opacity: 0.9;
    background-color: #2B2B2B;
}

.fas{
    font-size: 28px;
}

.test_skill{
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="testborder.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testbutton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-shipping-fast fa-inverse"></i></button>

        <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-address-card fa-inverse"></i></button>

        <!-- ici fa-inverse manquant -->
        <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-camera-retro"></i></button>

        <div id="skill_unlocked" onclick="myFunction()">
            <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-flag fa-inverse"></i></button>
        </div>

        <button class="btn"></button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things:

- When adding the class `test_skill` programmatically, you want to omit the dot 
  (you have `".test_skill"`).
- You'll probably want to add `onclick` and the ID `skill_unlocked` to the `<button>`, rather than the full-width containing `<div>`. In this case, you don't need the `<div>` at all.
- `.setAttribute("class", ...)` will actually **overwrite** the class(es) if you have an existing one. Instead, you really should use **[`.classList.add("test_skill")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)**.
- The class that you're adding is `test_skill`, yet you set up rules for `.test_skill_unlocked`. You'll want to ensure these match!

To add the border, you're looking to apply **[`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)** such as:

```
.test_skill {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

And instead of targeting the individual element, what I would recommend is to grab all of the buttons with **[`document.getElementsByClassName("btn")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)**. Note that this returns a **[NodeList collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** of elements, so you'll need to loop over them, adding an event handler to each. From here, you can use the JavaScript keyword **[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)** to refer to the button you're currently clicking on. This way, you can use the same function to add the bordered class to each button.

This can all be seen in the following:

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.add("test_skill");
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #575757;
}

.btn {
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border: 5px hidden;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  outline: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
}

.fas {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.test_skill {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="testborder.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testbutton.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-shipping-fast fa-inverse"></i></button>

  <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-address-card fa-inverse"></i></button>

  <!-- ici fa-inverse manquant -->
  <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-camera-retro"></i></button>

  <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-flag fa-inverse"></i></button>

  <button class="btn"></button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the knowledges and advices. It's working perfectly. Do you have an idea to make that border appears quarter-by-quarter ? 

It will use the same function 4 times to make different parts appear. Is it possible?

I was looking for that kind of structure (that function need to apply to each button)

Comment: In theory you would set `border-left`, `border-top`, etc. independently, and then 'trigger' each one to come into play with `.setTimeout()`. Things might get a little more complicated with circles though -- you may need `border-radius` as well :)

Comment: I don't get the  `js` code you wrote here. The  `var buttons` is ok, we are regrouping the `btn` class in one . But at the `for` i'm a bit lost. Don't understand how does it works (edit: works on the snippet not my files, weird)?

Comment: Ok, the script line on the hmtl file need to be placed at the end of the code just before `</body>` to work

Answer (score 3):

This is some code i was paying with. I think it does what you was asking but on hover not click. Not exactly what you need but maybe some ideas.

```js
$( ".hvr-ripple-out-good" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "fill-good" );
  });
```

```css
.hvr-ripple-out-good {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good:hover {
  color: #39CCCC;
  border-color: #39CCCC;
}

/* Ripple Out */
@-webkit-keyframes hvr-ripple-out {
  100% {
    top: -12px;
    right: -12px;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: -12px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-ripple-out {
  100% {
    top: -12px;
    right: -12px;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: -12px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) solid 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.hvr-ripple-out-good:hover:before, .hvr-ripple-out-good:focus:before, .hvr-ripple-out-good:active:before {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
  animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
  border-color: #39CCCC;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.fill-good {
  background-color: #39CCCC; 
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.fill-good:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.active {
  color: #61D6D6 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div style="padding: 100px; float: left;">

<a class="hvr-ripple-out-good"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple, you can achieve it with css only. No need to use scripts for this simple task, as this make the application heavy and it won't even work if the user has disabled JS in their browser.

Please find the code below for showing border on click (for desktop like devices) and on focus (for touch devices).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #575757;
    }
    
    .btn {
      margin: 10px;
      display: block;
      opacity: 0.6;
      border: 5px hidden;
      background-color: grey;
      border-radius: 50%;
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 70px;
      width: 70px;
      outline: none;
    }
    
    .btn:hover {
      opacity: 0.9;
      background-color: #2B2B2B;
    }
    /*   Show border on all buttons     */
    
    .btn:active,
    .btn:focus {
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
    
    .fas {
      font-size: 28px;
    }
    /*   
         * Remove comment for section below to Show border on specific button.
         */
    /*
                #skill_unlocked:active,
                #skill_unlocked:focus {
                    border: 2px solid red;
                }
        */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-shipping-fast fa-inverse"></i></button>
    <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-address-card fa-inverse"></i></button>
    <!-- ici fa-inverse manquant -->
    <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-camera-retro"></i></button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction()" id="skill_unlocked"><i class="fas fa-flag fa-inverse"></i></button>
    <button class="btn"></button>
  </body>

  </html>
</body>

</html>
```

***Answer to bonus Question***

The structure is not an issue in your case here. But, preferably use `<i>` within `<a>` if you want to create link on element within `<i>`

Answer (score 2):

Probably best to knock that out with pure CSS with the :active selector.

```
.btn:active {
   border: 5px solid red;
}
```

[Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p7xvrkzk/)

Comment: Either it's working to make the border appear. But that's not what I'm looking for.  The border don't stay if the button become inactive. I want to it constant when I'm cliking on it.

Comment: @Korkrane hm... maybe :focus then? That'd add the style when clicked and the style would stick around until the user clicked somewhere else.

Comment: Nice, but it seems to stick only to one button at a time. I'll keep searching to find what fits the best,hanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use this function

```
function myFunction() {
    var el = document.getElementById('skill_unlocked');
    el.classList.add("test_skill");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few good ways to do something like this. That said, I'd suggest using something other than an inline onclick attribute.

In this solution, I used `jQuery` and added an animation to the border with `CSS`. This gives the effect of the border appearing **quarter by quarter** 
 as per your OP and additional comments. You can play with the animation keyframes to get the border to appear in thirds, make it thicker, etc.

**Edit**: I made the border remain by adding the [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) `CSS` property and inserting the "filled" border segments at each keyframe in the animation.

Hope this helps!

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('test_skill');
  $(this).on('oanimationend webkitAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend', function() {
    //$(this).removeClass('test_skill');
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #575757;
}

.btn {
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border: none;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  outline: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
}

.fas {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.test_skill {
  animation: border .5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes border {
  0% {
    border-top: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    border-right: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom: 0px;
  }
  75% {
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    border-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    border-left: 2px solid red;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="testborder.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testbutton.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-shipping-fast fa-inverse"></i></button>

  <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-address-card fa-inverse"></i></button>

  <!-- ici fa-inverse manquant -->
  <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-camera-retro"></i></button>

  <div id="skill_unlocked">
    <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-flag fa-inverse"></i></button>
  </div>

  <button class="btn"></button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it's still helping me. Interesting to see how it works. In this situation, how the border could stay after the animation process ?

Answer (score 1):

Theres 2 problems:
1) Is you are calling the function setAttribute to add a class.
2) Structure doesnt make much sense , since the class you trying to add doesnt have any styles , so you can remove the

To make it work you could do this: 
add the on click and id attributes to the btn like so :

```
 <button class="btn" id="skill_unlocked" onclick="myFunction()">
```

and remove the border attr like this:

```
document.getElementById("btn").style.border = "none";
```

if you want to add a class you should do it like this ( but this wont do anything)  :

```
document.getElementById("skill_unlocked").classList.add('btn');
```

or to remove a class (this should remove all the styles):

```
document.getElementById("skill_unlocked").classList.remove('btn');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     var btn = $('.btn');
     btn.click(function(){
        $(btn).css('border','1px solid #000');
        $(this).css('border','1px solid #f00');
     })
  })
```

```css
.btn {
   width: 120px;
   height: 40px;
   display: inline-block;
   outline: none;
  }
  div {
   margin: 5px 0;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-shipping-fast fa-inverse"></i> Shipping</button>
 <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-address-card fa-inverse"></i> Address</button>
 <!-- ici fa-inverse manquant -->
    <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-camera-retro"></i> Camera</button>
 <div id="skill_unlocked">
        <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-flag fa-inverse"></i>Flag</button>
    </div>
 <button class="btn">Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```